# jQuery Toggle breaks layout w/ media query

Tags: jquery, layout, toggle

Not sure if this is a big deal. But wondering why when the site is scaled down and the menu button is toggled, that when you scale back up the whole layout has disappeared except the header.

You can see here: http://beta.revival.tv/

If you scale the site down, toggle the menu in the top right corner and leave it open, then scale back up, everything is gone except the header.

Just want to make sure this isn't due to bad written code.

Here is the jQuery handling the toggle:

```
 //menu toggle     
 $("#social-wrap li:nth-child(6)").click(function(){
   $("#phone-nav").slideToggle("slow");
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #phone-nav navigation element has a margin-top of -9999px. If I change that to 0, then the rest of the content shows. So, somehow, the elements are getting pushed up off of the screen, so it looks as if they've disappeared.

You need to find out what is changing that margin-top and fix that. - or explicitly set the placement of the #middle-wrap div to show on screen.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that. Fixing it right now. Appreciate your help.